# asynchronously change State in SwiftUI with strict concurrency setting enabled

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

I have this ButtonStyle in SwiftUI, the irrelevant parts of the animation itself got removed:

```
struct ChooseFileButto2n: ButtonStyle {
    @State private var animationComplete = false
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .onChange(of: animationComplete) { _ in
                Task {
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5*10^8)
                    if animationComplete {
                        animationComplete = false
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The idea is to reset the animation after some time. I get this error with strict concurrency checking enabled:
`` Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'ChooseFileButto2n' in a `@Sendable` closure ``
But the question should more be a general question on how to change a State variable in SwiftUI in an asynchronous context.
I tried doing it with DispatchQueue, tried setting a .task modifier and let a separate function listen for the changes, I tried to make it just a separate async function, setting it to @Sendable, but no matter what I try, as soon as I call anything changing that state, I get this warning.

Comment: Did you end up with a solution for this? I'm wrapping the view update inside an `await MainActor.run { ... }` and afaict that's the correct way of doing it but the warnings are still there. How else would you do this?

Comment: @fer0n I removed the button completely by now and I switched to the default ones. In a View State updates Inside a task work as a View seems to be Sendable. I did not try it but maybe setting ``@preconcurrency import SwiftUI`` silences it or somehow trying to conform ``ButtonStyle`` to Sendable

Answer (score 0):

To use async/await in SwiftUI it's `.task` not `Task {}` this is because the `View` struct is a value type that has no lifetime but the mechanics behind `.task` use a trick - it creates a state (that is stored in an object) during `onAppear` to manage a `Task` lifetime for you. Take a look at this backport to see how it likely is implemented:

https://github.com/shaps80/SwiftUIBackports/blob/main/Sources/SwiftUIBackports/Shared/Task/Task.swift

Comment: All `.task` does is to automatically use a `.onDisappear { task?.cancel() ...`, or am I missing something? Isn't it the same as calling `.onAppear { Task { ...` yourself?

Comment: If you use `.task(id:)` it also restarts when `id` changes.